# fetch CSV skipping header

Tags: javascript, csv

I've a simple function for read a csv file and works good! but i want to skip the header and start to use it from 2nd line

`CSV`

```
| date              | open    | high    | close  | low     | volume  |
+───────────────────+─────────+─────────+────────+─────────+─────────+
| 2022-05-15 18:00  | 25.652  | 33.451  | 26.185 | 23.146  | 486.651 |
```

`JS`
`

```
const getData = async () => {
    const res   = await fetch('data.csv');
    const resp  = await res.text();
    const cdata = resp.split('\n').map((row) => {
      const [date, open, high, low, close, volume] = row.split(',');
      return {
        date:   date,
        open:   open,
        high:   high,
        low:    low,
        close:  close,
        volume: volume,
      };
    });
    return cdata;
    //   console.log(cdata);
  };
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do `.split('\n').slice(1).map((row) => {`

```js
const data = `col1,col2
1,2
3,4`

console.log(data.split('\n').slice(1))
```

Comment: Thanks! It was so simple!